# Found incompatible Titanium Modules for GCM Integration

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to integrate `GCM` in titanium appcelerator.

I have integrated **net.iamyellow.gcmjs** module in my titanium project. But getting following error.

> [ERROR] :  Found incompatible Titanium Modules:   [ERROR] :     id:
>   net.iamyellow.gcmjs    version: 0.2    platform: android   min sdk:
>   3.0.2.GA

and my `titanium SDK` version is `6.1.2.GA`.

Answer (score 0):

To help you get started, [here are some good guidelines](http://iamyellow.net/post/40100981563/gcm-appcelerator-titanium-module). Also, you will find example of codes that will help you or at least give you an idea what's wrong with your code and why it gives you that error. You can compare your codes from the code provided in the site.

> Let’s start with a few lines of configuration. Open the tiapp.xml file
>   of your Titanium project since we need to declare the module first.
>   Once done, gcm.js only needs one property to make things work: the
>   sender id. As you see in the following example, just fill the property
>   value with that info:

```
<property name="GCM_sender_id" type="string">YOUR_SENDER_ID</property>
<modules>
    <module platform="android" version="0.2">net.iamyellow.gcmjs</module>
</modules>
```

> Now, somewhere in your app you’ll need to register it for push
>   notifications:

```
var gcm = require('net.iamyellow.gcmjs')

var pendingData = gcm.data;
if (pendingData && pendingData !== null) {
    // if we're here is because user has clicked on the notification
    // and we set extras for the intent 
    // and the app WAS NOT running
    // (don't worry, we'll see more of this later)
    Ti.API.info('******* data (started) ' + JSON.stringify(pendingData));
}

gcm.registerForPushNotifications({
    success: function (ev) {
        // on successful registration
        Ti.API.info('******* success, ' + ev.deviceToken);
    },
    error: function (ev) {
        // when an error occurs
        Ti.API.info('******* error, ' + ev.error);
    },
    callback: function () {
        // when a gcm notification is received WHEN the app IS IN FOREGROUND
        alert('hellow yellow!');
    },
    unregister: function (ev) {
        // on unregister 
        Ti.API.info('******* unregister, ' + ev.deviceToken);
    },
    data: function (data) {
        // if we're here is because user has clicked on the notification
        // and we set extras in the intent 
        // and the app WAS RUNNING (=> RESUMED)
        // (again don't worry, we'll see more of this later)
        Ti.API.info('******* data (resumed) ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});

// in order to unregister:
// require('net.iamyellow.gcmjs').unregister();
```

Just explore the site to have an expanded view of the tricks.

Hope this helps.